# How to get notified when system locale changes in Android?

Tags: android, localization

I'm regularly passing phone's locale as part of URL to the server.

```
private static String getLocaleStr() {
     Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
     return locale.getLanguage() + locale.getCountry();
}
```

I don't want to recall `getLocalStr()` every time I generate a URL. Is there a way to get notified when system locale changes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An Intent is broadcast for this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED